# How to store values in a Vec from inside a callback that does not take the vec as an argument?

Tags: function, lambda, rust, arguments, closures

I'm working with a crate which has a callback function mechanism. The callback is user defined but has a specific signature which does not allow for other values to be passed. For instance:

```rust
fn callback(id: u32, value: u32) -> u32;

// and would be used as such
library_function(callback);
```

So this would be fine If I only needed to save to a file or print for instance, however I need to save the values to a vector.
What I would've done in, for example Python, is using a lambda with "predefined" arguments:

```py
def mycallback(predefined, id, value)

# and calling it as such
predefined = []
library_function(lambda *args: mycallback(predifined, *args)
```

The solution can involve other tricks of Rust, however it can't be write to file each time since that seems like too much of a performance issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a closure:

```
let mut vec = Vec::new();
library_function(|id, value| {
    vec.push(value);
    id
});
```

The equivalent of your Python code would be:

```
fn callback(vec: &mut Vec<u32>, id: u32, value: u32) -> u32 {
    vec.push(value);
    id
}

fn main(){
    let mut predefined = Vec::new();
    library_function(|id, value| callback(&mut predefined, id, value));
}
```

---

The reason we call them *closures* is because they "close over" their environment. This allows us to use (and in this case modify) variables that are in the scope in which the closure is defined.

See:

- [Closures: Anonymous Functions that Can Capture Their Environment](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch13-01-closures.html) in the [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book).

Comment: @Dominus I highly recommend working your way through the book. There will be a lot of new concepts - even if you don't grasp them all at first, you will at least be familiar with what they are called.